# setindex! error in julia? when using "For loop" for DateTime

Tags: machine-learning, julia, artificial-intelligence, ijulia-notebook

I learn *Julia* from *Coursera*, And when I reached 2nd week lecture some codes error in my notebook.
It give me **setindex! not defined for WeakRefStrings.StringArray{String,1}** error.

[Csv File import here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk8n5.png)

```
using CSV, Dates
wikiEVDraw = CSV.read("wikipediaEVDraw1.csv")

Dates.DateTime.(wikiEVDraw[1,1],Ref("d-u-y"))
```

[Date Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxSdB.png)

```
col1=wikiEVDraw[:,1]
```

[setindex! error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P61W7.png)

```
for i = 1:length(col1)
    col1[i]=Dates.DateTime.(col1[i],Ref("d-u-y"))
end
```

Comment: Please copy-paste error messages as text, rather than posting screenshots. This helps us help you, and is overall beneficial to everybody.

Comment: Ok Sir, Next time I do not use screenshots

Comment: No worries, you couldn't possibly know how things are done, which is why I told you about this. FYI, here are some pieces of advice on how to ask "good" questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is because you forgot the dash (`-`) delimiter in your format string the second time.

Note that there is another error in your code: `col1` is of type `WeakRefStrings.StringArray` which is (AFAIU) not really a data type that is intended to be manipulated. And in any case, it is intended to store strings, so you can not replace its elements with `DateTime` objects instead.

Instead, you can build (a copy of) the entire column, with each element converted to a `DateTime` object. Broadcasting syntax would probably the most idiomatic way to do this:

```julia
# Sample data
julia> col = ["01-Jan-2020", "02-Jan-2020", "03-Jan-2020"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "01-Jan-2020"
 "02-Jan-2020"
 "03-Jan-2020"

julia> using Dates

       # Note the '.' before the open parenthesis
julia> col = Dates.DateTime.(col, Ref("d-u-y"))
3-element Array{DateTime,1}:
 2020-01-01T00:00:00
 2020-01-02T00:00:00
 2020-01-03T00:00:00
```

Comment: Yes, you'll see that the fix for that was already mentioned in my answer. I edited it to make it clearer why that happens